# Error with pip: '2020-resolver' invalid choice

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I'm encountering an error while using pip in my Python virtual environment. Whenever I try to upgrade pip or install a package, I receive the following error message:

"An error occurred during configuration: option use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver' (choose from 'fast-deps', 'truststore', 'no-binary-enable-wheel-cache')"

Steps to Reproduce:

Create a Python virtual environment using venv:

```
python -m venv myenv
```

Activate the virtual environment:

```
myenv\Scripts\activate
```

Attempt to upgrade pip using the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Expected Result:
I expect pip to be upgraded successfully without any errors.

Actual Result:
Instead, I receive the error message: "An error occurred during configuration: option use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver' (choose from 'fast-deps', 'truststore', 'no-binary-enable-wheel-cache')"

Additional Information:

I'm using Python version X.X.X.
I'm running Windows X operating system.
I have tried deleting the get-pip.py file and reinstalling pip, but the issue persists.
I have also tried creating a new virtual environment (myenv2), but the same error occurs.
Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you really using Python X.X.X and Windows X, or did you e.g. use ChatGPT to reformat this message and didn't think before sending it?

Comment: What does `pip config list` show you? I think you have a Pip configuration file or environment variable set to use a now-deprecated configuration option.

Comment: Python 3.11.3 I use and Windows 11.

Comment: C:\Users\ASUS>pip config list
An error occurred during configuration: option use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver' (choose from 'fast-deps', 'truststore', 'no-binary-enable-wheel-cache') (It showed same error)

Comment: Then you'll just need to find your Pip configuration file(s) by hand to remove this misconfiguration.

Comment: how i can remove them?

Comment: With your text editor.